# How to set whether brotil compression is enabled based on the value of the indicator in nginx

Tags: nginx

I want to set whether brotil compression is enabled based on the brotli_switch variable in nginx，this is my code， but nginx is wrong

```
server {
    listen 28880 reuseport default_server;

    location / {
        set $brotli_switch "on";

        if ( $brotli_switch = "on" ) {
            brotli on;
        }

        proxy_pass_header X-Accel-Buffering;
        proxy_pass http://node;
    }
}
```

can you help me？what should i do？